# Can we make the the tags look like the buttons in Lion?

Tags: feature-request, design

In chat today, [Timothy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/12285/timothy-mueller-harder) mentioned that the tags in oneboxes look a lot like the buttons in Windows XP:

[image: Picture of tags in oneboxes]

Compare to Windows XP button:
[image: Windows XP buttons]

Can we make the oneboxes *and* the tags on the main site look like the buttons from Lion? Like this:
[image]
I personally think that this will add more personality and a more OS X-ish feel to the site.

Answer (score 2):

I feel this would be a very poor design decision.

Apple's HIG specifically calls out "***Do not use a push button as a label***."

The OS X button style is reserved for clickable UI elements and if we used them on items that are not Cocoa controls and instead web links - I feel it would undermine the clarity of purpose that [OS X provides under it's Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000894-TP6). *And that's the best spin on it for people browsing from OS X browsers.*

It **gets worse** if you are browsing from an [iOS device](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) where the button treatment uses another idiom. Likewise Ubuntu, Windows, Android, etc….

I get the wish to have pretty things - but I'd personally rather a "design is how it works" interpretation here over a "design is how it looks" design.

Thankfully, the site has redesigned the tag buttons and they look very nice on both retina and non-retina screens of all OS (*again perhaps only in my opinion*).

[image: redesigned tag button design from June 2013]